# Sidebar to show currently displayed markers - combined IF statement

Tags: if-statement, google-maps-api-3, checkbox, sidebar

I would really appreciate some help with this problem. It may be easy to solve but I just can't figure out how to go about coding it. I have a map based on this [Geocodezip Example Categories](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html) which displays markers and has a sidebar next to it. The markers belong to one of three categories and based on whether the checkboxes are checked, the markers will appear on the map.

```
    function show(category) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
            if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
                gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
    }

    function hide(category) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
            if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
                gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
        infowindow.close();
    }
```

At the same time, I am trying to display the markers' info in the sidebar but under two conditions:

1. the marker category must be checked &
2. the marker must be contained in the map viewport/bounds

I then added one code for the sidebar that only displays the markers for checked categories and one where the info is shown in the sidebar when the markers are in the viewport. However, I can only do these separately (for to completely different codes) and cannot get both conditions to work together. These are the two examples that I am trying to merge:

1. Include in sidebar if box is checked

   ```
   function makeSidebar() {
       var side_bar_html = "";
       for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
           if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
               side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
           }
       }
       document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
   }
   ```
2. (when bounds change) Include in sidebar if marker is contained within bounds

   ```
   function makeSidebar() {
       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
           var side_bar_html = "";
           var bounds = map.getBounds();       
           for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
               if (bounds.contains(gmarkers[i].position)) {
                   side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
               }
           }
           document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;  
       });
   }
   ```

I tried putting the two together in a combined if statement (&&) within the if bounds.contains statement but the sidebar won't change if a box is checked/unchecked.

Comment: Thank you for posting your code, it really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the check to makeSidebar only when the map bounds is available:

```
  // == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
  function makeSidebar() {
    var html = "";
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()  && 
          map.getBounds && 
          map.getBounds() && 
          map.getBounds().contains(gmarkers[i].getPosition())) {
        html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
  }
```

execute makeSidebar when the bounds_changed event fires:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', makeSidebar);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXRG5/)

Comment: Thanks as usual! Btw, can I ask what is the reasoning behind all those map.getBounds?

Comment: Defensive programming, if map doesn't have a getBounds method, or that method returns null, you don't want to try to run the contains method of null, it will fail.  It happens the makeSidebar method runs (while the map is still initializing).